# Ajax post / insert into database not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to ajax and got an problem submitting a form an send the data via ajax.
Getting the data from the database isn't a problem. But the inserting wont work and i didn't find a mistake.

My form file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function showComment(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"./includes/ajax.comments.php",
                data:"post_id=<?PHP echo $post->post_id ?>&action=show",
                success:function(data){
                    $("#comments").html(data);
                }
            });
        }

        showComment();
        $("#fastReply").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var comment_text = $("#txtArea").val();
            var comment_user_id = <?PHP echo $current_user->user_id; ?>;
            var comment_post_id = <?PHP echo $post->post_id; ?>;
            $.ajax({
                type:"post",
                url:"./includes/ajax.comments.php",
                data: "comment_title=null&comment_text="+comment_text+"&comment_user_id="+comment_user_id+"&comment_post_id="+comment_post_id+"comment_status=1&action=add",
                success: function(data){
                    showComment();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<form action="post">
    <textarea id="txtArea"></textarea>
    <button id="fastReply" type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

And my php file is looking like this

```
if($action == "add"){
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    $comment_title      = $_POST["comment_title"];
    $comment_text       = $_POST["comment_text"];
    $comment_user_id    = $_POST["comment_user_id"];
    $comment_post_id    = $_POST["comment_post_id"];
    $comment_status     = $_POST["comment_status"];

    $query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO comments(comment_title, comment_text, comment_user_id, comment_post_id, comment_status) 
                                VALUES('".$comment_title."', '".$comment_text."', ".$comment_user_id.", ".$comment_post_id.", ".$comment_status.")");

    if($query){
        echo "Your comment has been sent";
    } else {
        echo "Error in sending your comment";
    }
}
```

I also doesn't find an other question which helps me

Comment: Do one thing. Replace `$mysqli->query` with `die` and copy the query and paste it in phpMyAdmin or Adminer or whatever, and tell what you see. Also show what you get the query as.

Comment: Try  ".$comment_status." to ' ".$comment_status."'

Comment: Do you get anything returned to the browser. And what does `showComment()` do, you are not passing `data` to that function is that the problem. Check in the debugger

Comment: `data: {comment_title: null, comment_text: comment_text, comment_user_id: comment_user_id, comment_post_id: comment_post_id: comment_status: 1, action:add},`

Comment: You are wide open for SQL-injections. You should really use prepared statements

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know that, but for testing it isn't needed to prevent

Comment: _but for testing it isn't needed to prevent_ Yea, yea, we all know what that means

Comment: @RiggsFolly i tried your advice but it dosn't work anyway

Comment: You're checking: `$action == "add"`... have you stored `$_POST['action']` in that variable?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson at the end of `data` I say `action=add`

Comment: Ok ok  Are you sure that the PHP script is actually getting run.

Comment: @RiggsFolly before I tried to use Ajax I had all in one file and it works fine

Comment: @DestinatioN - You still need to fetch the `action` value from the `$_POST  `-super global, just like you do with the other parameters: `if($_POST['action'] == "add")`

Comment: _before I tried to use Ajax I had all in one file and it works fine_ Not particularly relevant. If you changed how it works, thats when little mistakes get overlooked

Comment: sorry - that was my fault - the OP replied to that effect (the $action variable being set) as a comment to my post which was asking about that - but because he has, the post was redundant so I deleted it and so deleted that confirming comment.

Comment: Ok. I went mad, reading it all over and over trying to find that info. :)

Comment: Do you know how to use your browsers **javascript debugger** If you do, what is returned in the `data` parameter of `success: function(data){` add an `alert(data);` if you dont know how to use the **browsers debugger**

Comment: sorry mate -@Magnus Eriksson. DestinatioN - what about the "comment_title=null" - is that field in the db allowed to have a null value?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried your answer with the object and now it works

Comment: Cool, got there eventually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
function showComment(id){
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"./includes/ajax.comments.php",
        data:{post_id:id,action:'show'},//convert to object
        success:function(data){
            $("#comments").html(data);
        }
    });
}

$("#fastReply").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var comment_text = $("#txtArea").val();
    var comment_user_id = '<?PHP echo $current_user->user_id; ?>';//convert to string
    var comment_post_id = '<?PHP echo $post->post_id; ?>';//convert to string
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"./includes/ajax.comments",
        data: {
            comment_title: null,
            comment_text: comment_text,
            comment_user_id: comment_user_id,
            comment_post_id: comment_post_id,
            comment_status: 1,
            action: 'add'
        },//convert to object
        success: function(data){
            showComment(id);//pass the id
        }
    });
});
```

Php

```
$action = $_POST['action'];//get the action value
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the file extension on the "includes/ajax.comments" on the second AJAX call which is triggered on the fastReply click and so will not run

```
$("#fastReply").click(function(e){...//this section
//other code
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"./includes/ajax.comments.php",//this is where it is missing & i added it
        data: "comment_title=null&comment_text="+comment_text+"&...
```

Comment: @gravgrif I added the file exteion but it doesn't works anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($_POST["action"] == "add")
{
    header("Content-``Type: application/json", true);
    $comment_title      = $_POST["comment_title"];
    $comment_text       = $_POST["comment_text"];
    $comment_user_id    = $_POST["comment_user_id"];
    $comment_post_id    = $_POST["comment_post_id"];
    ....
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.